# Android data binding spinner adapter

Tags: android, adapter, android-spinner, android-databinding, android-binding-adapter

I have to write a `@BindingAdapter` which accepts Spinner and `EnumSet<T>` :

```
@BindingAdapter(value = {"android:entries"})
public static <T extends Enum<T> & ITextable> void bindSpinnerData(Spinner spinner, EnumSet<T> entries) {
    spinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<T>(spinner.getContext(), R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, new ArrayList<>(entries)) {
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            ITextable item = getItem(position);
            textView.setText(item.getText());
            return v;
        }

        @Override
        public View getDropDownView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
            TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            ITextable item = getItem(position);
            textView.setText(item.getText());
            return v;
        }
    });
}
```

I have a problem because if the text of a `Spinner` item is too long to fit into a single line, the text is not wrapped but cut off like this:

[image]

Can anyone tell my where and what I should change to wrap the text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually not a databinding-issue. It's because TextView arent wrapped by default and also doesnt have elipses if you dont set them.

You may want to try either to create your own Layout which gets inflated, or you may use

```
textView.setSingleLine(false)
textView.setMaxLines(2)
```

If this doesnt work you need to overwrite `getDropDownView`

```
@Override
public View getDropDownView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = new TextView(_context);
    }

    TextView item = (TextView) convertView;
    item.setText(yourItems.getItem(position));
    final TextView finalItem = item;
    item.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            finalItem.setSingleLine(false);
        }
    });
    return item;
}
```

Easiest solution is just switch your Spinner using dialog design by putting this into your xml.

```
 <Spinner android:spinnerMode="dialog" />
```

Comment: I try to setSinglLine on textView but it doesnt work. I set spinnerMode as dialog, it works. Thank you

Comment: Finally i use second option with override getDopDownView